# No two sided limit exists

Tags: limits, infinity, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to calculate the limit of

$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^x -1)}{(x^2)}$

I tried L'Hospital and apparently as it diverges and twice applied you get $\frac{1}{2}$. This is wrong apparently. How can I stop this mistake from happening, what can I spot beforehand?

Comment: For small $x$, $e^x -1 \approx x$, so the quotient behaves as ${x \over x^2}$.

Comment: Not a proof, just a thought: Did you make a graph?

Comment: No i didn't feel confident plotting it without desmos etc.

Comment: If you differentiate the numerator and evaluate at $x=0$ you get $1$ while the denominator evaluates to $0$. That should be a warning sign. I don't know here you got the ${1 \over 2}$ from.

Comment: Differentiate again

Comment: The limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ equals the derivative of the exponential function at the origin, i.e. $1$. It follows that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x^2}$ does not exist, simply.

Comment: I graphed, and it is evident what is going on. The problem is in the denominator where the power is 2. Had it been a linear term, the limit would have existed. Not sure what tools you are allowed to use, but with Taylor series you can see why

Comment: L'Hospital's rule has **conditions**. In the usual form, you need that $f(x)\to0$ and $g(x)\to0$ as $x\to a$. After applying the Hospital once you get $e^x/1$, and $e^x\not\to0$ as $x\to0$ and certainly $1\not\to0$ as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 5):

If you apply L'hospital once you get

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x}{2x}.$$

Since the numerator of this goes to $1$, you can't apply L'hospital a
second time.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=e^x$

Then $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=f'(0)=1$

Using this you can conclude that the side limits are different thus the limit does not exist